# Map with only certain keys

Tags: scala

With regard to maps in Scala, if `ms - (k, 1, m)` returns the map containing all mappings of ms **except** for any mapping with the given keys, x, 1 and m.

Then, what statement will return a map of all mappings of ms with **only**  the given keys, x, 1 and m. i.e. I'm looking for the subset of ms where only k, 1 and m are keys.

This works, but it is terrible:

```
scala> val originalMap = Map("age" -> "20", "name" -> "jack", "hobby" -> "jumping")
ms: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(age -> 20, name -> jack, hobby -> jumping)

scala> val interestingKeys = List("name", "hobby")
interesting: List[java.lang.String] = List(name, hobby)

scala> val notInterestingMap = originalMap -- interestingKeys
notInterestingMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(age -> 20)

scala> val interestingMap = originalMap -- notInterestingMap.keySet
interestingMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(name -> jack, hobby -> jumping)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `filterKeys` filters based on an arbitrary predicate, it has to consider every key in the map. This might be fine or not, depending on how large the map is, etc., but it's definitely not necessary  for the operation you describe. I'd use something like the following:

```
interestingKeys.flatMap(k => originalMap.get(k).map((k, _))).toMap
```

This will be `O(n)` or `O(n log m)` depending on your map implementation (where `n` is the size of `interestingKeys` and `m` is the size of the map), instead of `O(m log n)` or `O(mn)`.

If you really want your `~` operator, you can use the [pimp-my-library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766):

```
class RichMap[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) {
  def ~(ks: A*) = ks.flatMap(k => m.get(k).map((k, _))).toMap
}

implicit def enrichMap[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) = new RichMap(m)
```

Now `originalMap ~ ("name", "hobby")` returns `Map(name -> jack, hobby -> jumping)`, as you'd expect.

Comment: For those using AKKA persistence it worth to mention that `filterKeys` output is _not_ serializable, I faced that and it took a while till I realised. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6654

Answer (score 10):

`filterKeys`can help:

```
scala> originalMap.filterKeys(interestingKeys.contains)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(name -> jack, hobby -> jumping)
```

Comment: possible improvement with interestingKeys.toSet` instead of `interestingKeys contains`, as checking membership into a set is likely to be be more efficient. Not with a two elements list however.

Comment: and not if you pass a list of distinc elements. It clearly depends on the context.

Comment: Why would distinct elements change that? Membership testing would still be O(n) rather than O(1) or O(log n) for a typical set implementation.

Comment: Thanks a stack. It's a bit surprising though, I would have expected something like ms ~ (k, 1, m) where ~ denotes a fictional operator that processes the intersection of keys between a map and a list and returns the resulting map.

Comment: @didierd: Yep I figure it out afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original code is not that bad, and it can be easily transformed into a one-liner operating on key sets:

```
val interestingMap = originalMap -- (originalMap.keySet -- interestingKeys)
```

I find this quite readable.